# Take value from jquery slider

Tags: jquery

I am trying to take values from `jquery slider` interactively but its not working. What might be missing here?
My code is as follows:

```
jquery:
var min_val = 0.5;
var max_val = 10;
var default_val = 5;

$('#teaching').slider({
    min: min_val,
    max: max_val,
    value: default_val,
    step: 0.1,
    slide: function(event, ui){
        $('#feed1').html(ui.value);
        var list_value = ui.value;

        $('#teaching_hidden').val(ui.value); //problem here


        if(list_value < 4){
            $('#feed1_img').attr('src','images/sad.png');
        }else if(list_value >= 4 && list_value < 6){
            $('#feed1_img').attr('src','images/confused.png');
        }else if(list_value >= 6 && list_value < 9){
            $('#feed1_img').attr('src','images/like.png');
        }else{
            $('#feed1_img').attr('src','images/happy.png');
        }   
    } 
});
```

The value of a is supposed to be changing dynamically But If i try to print is out the output is `[object Object]` random number of time. Please help.

My aim is to store `ui.value` in `teaching_hidden` which is a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('#teaching_hidden').val(ui.value);
```

Right now, `a` replaces the value of `#teaching_hidden` with the value of `ul.value`.

One doesn't typically replace a value in a `var`.

What do you want here?  Do you want the value of `#teaching_hidden` or the value of `ui.value`?  Right now, `a` isn't set to a variable.  It's a function that runs inside of a variable to replace the value of one element with the value of another.

If you wanted the value of either of those elements, you would do:

```
var a = $('#teaching_hidden').val();
```

OR

```
var a = $('ui.value').val();
```

**EDIT**  Also, please note that `.val()` is used to retriece the `value=` attribute from an element, not it's inner string.  If you wanted that, you would user `$('#element').html();`

Read up on the differences.

http://api.jquery.com/val/

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: I have edited the question. This sample is from my practice code when I was trying things. My goal is to assign `ui.value` to `teaching_hidden`.

Comment: You need to put your HTML markup in the question as well.  Without seeing what you're trying to manipulate, it's hard to troubleshoot.   If you want the current value, then `var a = $('#teaching_hidden').val();`  The value that will replace it is, `var a = $('ul.value').val();`.  Then just put it into a test div.  `$('#test').html(a)`;Just remember that it's `<div id="teaching_hidden" value="myVal"></div>` and not <div id="teaching_hidden">myVal</div>`.